# Generating Random UIImages that don't repeat

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

In my app project I am displaying 107 of my images at random, I have set up a for loop that puts all of my images into an array. I then take that array and choose a random Index. That index correlates to a picture and then that picture appears on the screen when the user swipes to the left. My question is that can I make it so my code will not repeat the same index in the array until all of them (or the amount until closing the app) have been chosen at random. Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pictureArray: [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var quoteImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...107{
        pictureArray.append("quote\(i).jpg")
        print(pictureArray)
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (changeQuotes))
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true
}


@objc func changeQuotes(){

    let numberOfImages: UInt32 = 107
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pictureArray.count)))
    let imageName = "\(pictureArray[randomIndex])"
    print(imageName)
    quoteImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)


    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: randomise the array the use .dropFirst() or .dropLast() ?

Comment: Have you searched on non-repeating arrays? Why are you narrowing - by question title - down to `UIImage`? Poor choice all around.

Answer (score 2):

Flush your array randomly, then just get the "sorted" image one by one.

```
extension Sequence {
    func randomSorted() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        guard result.count > 1 else { return result }

        for (i, k) in zip(result.indices, stride(from: result.count, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let newIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(k)))
            if newIndex == i { continue }
            result.swapAt(i, newIndex)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique random number by managing 2 arrays one contains images that are not yet displayed and one that are already displayed

Make following changes in your code

```
var pictureArray: [String] = []
var selectedPictureArray: [String] = []

static let TOTAL_IMAGES = 108

@IBOutlet weak var quoteImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fillPictureArray()
    let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (changeQuotes))
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
}

func fillPictureArray() {

    self.selectedPictureArray.removeAll()
    for i in 0..<ViewController.TOTAL_IMAGES {
        pictureArray.append("quote\(i).jpg")
    }
    print(pictureArray)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true
}


func changeQuotes(){

    if self.pictureArray.count == 0 {

        self.fillPictureArray()
    }

    var randomIndex = 0
    while true {

        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ViewController.TOTAL_IMAGES)))
        if self.selectedPictureArray.contains("quote\(randomIndex).jpg") {
            continue
        }else {
            break
        }
    }
    let imageName = "quote\(randomIndex).jpg"
    self.selectedPictureArray.append(imageName)
    print(imageName)
    quoteImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let index = self.pictureArray.index(of: imageName)
    self.pictureArray.remove(at: index!)
}
```

Happy coding :)